# Wordpress Invalid image URL when using media_sideload_image

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the wordpress function **media_sideload_image** to upload images from an external link like below:

```
   $url = 'http://pinnaclepublic.pinewoodsa.co.za/vehicles/plugins/ViewImage.aspx?guid=F92A44F3-71AC-4B2C-8BC4-8CC53578B722&VehicleId=101887&ImageNumber=1&Size=3';
   $post_id = 101;

   media_sideload_image ($url,$post_id);
```

But I get the error:

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [image_sideload_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Invalid image URL
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

**Question:**
How can I make media_sideload_image, work properly with this particular url which I cannot change.

Comment: are you using this function outside the context of /wp-admin/?

Comment: Permissions on your `wp-cotent` folder?

Comment: sorry how do i check this, i am not really sure. i am working on a plugin which fetches images from an external link and attaches them to a custom post type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Problem:**

Its a problem with the URL. The *file* module of Wordpress can't recognize any file extension from the URL you're giving it. And hence throws this error.
Have a look at the source code of this function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_sideload_image/

**Solution:**

I was facing this problem for the past hour. After severe headache, I was able to use a hack around it.

> All you got to do is append some random Query Param at the end of the
> URL that equals to the ".jpeg" or ".png".

**Example:**

```
$url = 'http://pinnaclepublic.pinewoodsa.co.za/vehicles/plugins/ViewImage.aspx?guid=F92A44F3-71AC-4B2C-8BC4-8CC53578B722&VehicleId=101887&ImageNumber=1&Size=3';
$url_with_pseudo_extension = $url . '?ext=.jpeg'
```

This will let the URL walk out safely from the file module without throwing any errors.

Comment: incidentally, the same error will be presented if trying to use media_sideload_image from the same IP address as the URL you are trying to download.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using this function outside the context of `/wp-admin`
you need to include media.php and depending includes.

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
```

See the notes for the documentation of [media_sideload_image()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image)

You can also create your own function like this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30284/media-sideload-image-file-name?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: sorry but to be honest i am not sure if i am outside context of /wp-admin. what is the simple way to know this

Comment: you are using this function outside wp-admin. you could try to require those files. Though I haven't tried it yet.